# file structure of big node js projects

Tags: node.js, express

I am building a big blog application with express and my question is about how big blogs and big applications structure their files.

For my application, I am making a new ejs file for every blog article that I write. I am doing this because each blog article that I write has a different amount of pictures, different headings, etc. However, I am realizing that there are a lot of files building up.

```
Is there a better way of doing this?
```

I thought of storing the article contents in the database but due to the contents of each article being different I didn’t think this was viable.

something like this

```
let articleText = query db for article text;
res.render("article.ejs", {blog_cotent: articleText});
```

Comment: @pzaenger Thanks but this does not really answer my question whatsoever!

Comment: You should be able to use the same EJS template for each blog entry, so "yes" there is a better way of doing it.  For us to help more specifically, we would need to see how you're storing and naming your images and how you know which images go with which blog post.  Shouldn't headings be part of the content itself which is unique for each blog post and not part of the EJS template?

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for your response. Yes, the headings would be part of the content which is unique.. you are right. Now my question is... if every article should use the same ejs template, what do I do when articles have images in different places within the article? Or, how would I handle article one containing a list of steps while article two does not contain that list?

Comment: Can't your unique content for each blog contain EJS and insert it in a way that it gets processed as part of the template?  So, you could use EJS commands in your content.  Or, you could make your own simple tags in the content that your JS processes and inserts the right things (but it would be better to just let EJS do that work).

Comment: @jfriend00 ohhhhhh that makes so much sense. Totally fixed my problem! Thank you so much!

Comment: you can use handlebar to insert information for dynamic content instead of creating seprately

Comment: @JatinMehrotra - They've already got EJS to do that which serves the same general template function as Handlerbars for inserting dynamic content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For my application, I am making a new ejs file for every blog article that I write. I am doing this because each blog article that I write has a different amount of pictures, different headings, etc. However, I am realizing that there are a lot of files building up.

> Is there a better way of doing this?

You should be able to use the same EJS template for each blog entry, so "yes" there is a better way of doing it. For us to help more specifically, we would need to see how you're storing and naming your images and how you know which images go with which blog post. Shouldn't headings be part of the content itself which is unique for each blog post and not part of the EJS template?

> Yes, the headings would be part of the content which is unique.. you are right. Now my question is... if every article should use the same ejs template, what do I do when articles have images in different places within the article? Or, how would I handle article one containing a list of steps while article two does not contain that list?

Can't your unique content for each blog contain EJS and insert it in a way that it gets processed as part of the template? So, you could use EJS commands in your content. Or, you could make your own simple tags in the content that your JS processes and inserts the right things (but it would be better to just let EJS do that work).